# toExponential() on Infinity number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get like first 7-8 numbers after digit on a number that is `Infinity`.

I.E. `console.log((4^3)/(3^3));` will result in an `Infinity` while the real result is `2.370370370...`. What I want is to get that number in `2.370370370e+-60` form.

I tried to make it with `result.toExponential(8);` but no effects so far. Any tips/answers would be appreciated.

Comment: do you want Math.pow(4, 3), or 4 xor 3?

Comment: If the runtime math-calculation engine of your language decides for whatever reason that the answer is `Infinity` (or "arithmetic overflow"), then unfortunately you *have no* answer. And, JavaScript really doesn't provide for alternative means to perform the calculation, that I am aware of.

Comment: What you are computing here is "(4 XOR 3) / (3 XOR 3)" which equals to 7 / 0 = Inifinity

Comment: @RegisPortalez Thanks for pointing that out. `Math.pow(4, 3)` is the thing i'm looking for. And that indeed made the thing working. Thank you all for your answers x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, exponentiation is made by the `Math.pow` function. There is no inline operator like `^` (as in python with `**`).

You should instead compute

```
Math.pow(4, 3) / Math.pow(3, 3)
```

A part from that,

you were computing `(4 XOR 3) / (3 XOR 3)`, which evaluates to 7 / 0, which is an  [Infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Infinities).